# Firebase Java Android Check if a child was not created because it was the same as another already present in the same parent

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, children

I am developing a login and registration system with java for an android app. I use firebase to register users with email and password and the email, username and other information will form an inheritance structure on the realtime db firebase as parent there is the user id:

[image: User data]

However, I want the usernames to be unique and so that if a user writes a username already present in the parent Usernames he recognizes that there is another child that is the same. Since firebase doesn't allow you to create children with the same name I tried to do something like this:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Usernames").child(us.getText().toString()).setValue("Saved").addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not same username", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "same username", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
```

But I don't understand why, the answer is always OnCompleted, even when the child has the same name as another and therefore a user has entered a username already entered.

Could someone tell me how I can check if the Firebase db did not insert the child because it was named the same as another

Here are my current database rules:

```json
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "true",  
    ".write": "true",
  }
}
```

[image: RTDB structure]

Full Code: https://codeshare.io/Gq880j

Comment: Don't modify the code from the original question with code from answers, leave it as it was when you first asked it.

Comment: Ok @samthecodingman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the username exists yourself like this:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Usernames").child(us.getText().toString());
rootRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.exists()) {
      // Username is already taken
    } else {
      // Username is available, add the data
    }
  }
});
```

That's probably the easiest way to do it. If you use the update operation directly, it'll overwrite the existing values.

Comment: I tried to add your code (look on the question, I updated the code with the code I added) but it keeps giving me "Us already ex" every time ... I don't understand why

Comment: @pophome please share a complete screenshot of your DB, maybe the path is wrong.

Comment: @pophome I just noticed I forgot to remove setValue. Can you try the updated code ?

Comment: I have tried your updated code but it continues to output the toast of username not taken in all cases

Comment: @pophome that's strange, can you try hardcoding a name instead of `us.getText()` ? So we can confirm the output is okay. Also, it is case sensitive. So `myNaMe` and `MYnAme` are same. Makee sure you have all names in lowercase both in db and request.

Comment: @pophome I am confused with the second question. Also if this is a separate question you should ideally post another one on stackoverflow so it's easier for future readers to find. But feel free to explain it.

Answer (score 1):

To start with, your code will never throw an exception stating that the username is already taken because your current rules give complete read & write access to your database.

```json
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "true",  
    ".write": "true",
  }
}
```

Instead of simply storing `"Saved"` under each username, you should store the user's ID. This will help later when you want to delete a user account or change their username. Then you need to [secure your RTDB with security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database). Both of these steps are covered in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67305111/3068190).

```json
"/usernames": {
  "bob": "userId1",
  "frank": "userId2",
  "c00lguy": "userId3"
}
```

To allow you to still develop your code, while allowing you to tighten it as you go, you can name specific trees to lock down:

```json
{
  "rules": {
    // only signed in users can read user data
    // only the related user can edit it
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth != null",
        ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid"
      },
    },

    // all other trees are globally read/write accessible
    // TODO: remove this rule
    "$other": {
      ".read": "true",
      ".write": "true"
    }
  }
}
```

So, to merge the restrictions on `/usernames` with your current database rules, you would use:

```json
{
  "rules": {
    "usernames": {
      "$username": {
        // world readable
        ".read": true,

        // must be logged in to edit, you can only claim free usernames OR delete owned usernames
        ".write": "auth != null && (!newData.exists() || auth.uid == newData.val()) && (!data.exists() || data.val() == auth.uid)",

        // strings only
        ".validate": "newData.isString()",
      }
    },

    // all other trees are globally read/write accessible
    // TODO: remove this rule
    "$other": {
      ".read": "true",
      ".write": "true"
    }
  }
}
```

Now that you have secured the database, you can claim the usernames as you are doing and it will now throw a permissions error if you try to overwrite a previously claimed username.

Importantly, because you are using [`addOnCompleteListener()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task#addOnCompleteListener(com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener%3CTResult%3E)), you need to check if the task has succeeded or failed first because your event handler's `onComplete()` method will be called in either case. This also removes the need for using [`addOnFailureListener()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task#addOnFailureListener(com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener)).

```java
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
    .getReference("Usernames")
    .child(us.getText().toString()) // <- the desired username
    .setValue(uid) // <- who is claiming it
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have claimed this username.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "That username was taken.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Reproducing the [linked answer's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67305111/3068190) utility methods:

```
public Task<Boolean> isUsernameTaken(String username) {
    return FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
        .getReference("Usernames")
        .child(username)
        .get() // <- forces getting value from server
        .onSuccessTask(snapshot -> Tasks.forResult(snapshot.exists));
}

public Task<Void> claimUsername(String username) {
    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    if (user == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("User must be signed in first.");
    }
    return FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
        .getReference("Usernames")
        .child(username) // <- the desired username
        .setValue(user.getUid()) // <- who is claiming it
}
```

Comment: Should I now put all the code inside fAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword? this is because otherwise I cannot get the uid. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @pophome Once a user has been successfully authenticated, you can now use `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()` anywhere in your code to get the currently logged in user. You can either add the first block of code inside your `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` chain or use `claimUsername(us.getText().toString()).addOnCompleteListener(...)`. It's up to you. Personally I favour using functions for understanding the code better.

Comment: the rules you suggested how should I insert them? do i still have to leave read and write true? I have updated my application with the current rules

Comment: @pophome I have updated the answer with information related to your current rules

Comment: I updated the question with the error I get if I paste the rules

Comment: @pophome That was my bad, I was missing a comma

Comment: I added your code but registering with username already entered it keeps showing the taost: 'You have claimed this username'.
Maybe I'm doing something wrong. I have updated my application with the link to the full code. The part that interests us is on line 77

Comment: @pophome Is that true even when trying to claim a username taken by **another user**? With the current rules, it won't reject claiming the same username from the same user.

Comment: Yes that's right, maybe I got something wrong about the rules .. I don't know